# Bootstrap css not working in ie8, ie8 show all bootstrap class 100%,

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

Bootstrap css not working in ie8, ie8 show all bootstrap class 100%, 
i use this

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7" />

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the joostrap it will be Supporting Internet Explorer 8 and 9
and try it
[www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9](http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9)